# What is the best way to test the ISO 106 signal isolation buffer amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, power-electronics, components, isolation, buffer

I need to test the ISO106 signal isolation buffer amplifier as part of my next task.  I went through the data sheet without getting any idea on how to test these ICs.

Basically, I need to test the functionality of this IC.

Can someone help me with this by explaining what it is and how to test it please?

Yes I already have boards which contains the ISO 106 and wish to check it. "GE COROMETRICS MEDICAL 11867FA REV 002 MODEL 122 ISOLATED UA/FECC ISO106" this is the board which has this ISO106 and would like to check the component with respect to this board.

I am going to remove the ISO106 and test it seperately.  Which parameters would be best to test it?

I know these are outdated products but it is part of my task so please help me out.

[Datasheet of the ISO106.](https://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf/download.php?id=002cfb941b8bd8ec6b6f8e8fa7f3e3621455ee&type=M&term=iso106)

Comment: Find a proper data sheet for this chip please and not one that only shows a dozen lines of information at a time.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "test" here?  Are you evaluating these and wish to put together some test circuits?  Are you purchasing some of these for an application and wish to test incoming quality? Are you producing some product containing these and wish to test your product?

Comment: Yes I am already having  boards which contains the ISO 106 and wish to check it. "GE COROMETRICS MEDICAL 11867FA REV 002 MODEL 122 ISOLATED UA/FECC ISO106" this is the board which has this ISO106  and would like to check the component w.r.t to this board. Basically I am going to remove the ISO106 and test it seperately so which parameters would be best to test it can you suggest please ....

Comment: What aspects do you need to test?  Function? Isolation? There are example circuits in the datasheet that cover both of those.  There's an example of measuring a high voltage, which would test both isolation and function.  There's an example of an isolated thermometer that would test function and precision.

Comment: Yes I studied the circuits in the data sheet but they are little complicated circuits for me. Can you suggest any other circuits by which I will be able to test its function and isolation please..?